# what do we mean by max packets in json

Tags: json

When we say a specific api can handle up to 200 packets, in json format what is a packet exactly? is it a key: value thing or the whole list is considered one packet?

```
[  
   {   //do we consider all this object as a packet?
      "timestamp":"2019-08-06T11:11:25Z", //or do we consider this key-value as a packet?
      "type":"Gateway",
      "mac":"AC233FC04294",
      "gatewayFree":91,
      "gatewayLoad":1.62
   },
   {  
      "timestamp":"2019-08-06T11:11:25Z",
      "type":"iBeacon",
      "mac":"AC233F2C779F",
      "bleName":"",
      "ibeaconUuid":"E2C56DB5DFFB48D2B060D0F5A71096E0",
      "ibeaconMajor":2,
      "ibeaconMinor":25,
      "rssi":-33,
      "ibeaconTxPower":-59,
      "battery":0
   },
   {  
      "timestamp":"2019-08-06T11:11:26Z",
      "type":"iBeacon",
      "mac":"AC233F523EA4",
      "bleName":"",
      "ibeaconUuid":"E2C56DB5DFFB48D2B060D0F5A71096E0",
      "ibeaconMajor":100,
      "ibeaconMinor":4,
      "rssi":-45,
      "ibeaconTxPower":-59,
      "battery":0
   }
]
```

the json above has 3 objects, each one with multi values, how many packets do we have?

Comment: A packet is not a JSON concept, but a concept of the API you are using. what you have here is a JSON array that consists of 3 JSON objects. anything else i could say would be an assumption. Please read the documentation of the API

Comment: That sounds like something API specific. You would have to clarify this with the provider of the API.

Comment: Oh, got it, thanks!